# Org timestamp ranges that cross midnight

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

Event durations are pretty straight forward to denote:

```
<2015-08-27 Thu 14:30-21:00>
```

But what about an event that extends past midnight?

```
<2015-08-27 Thu 22:30-01:30>
```

Does not do what I think it does. Additionally, giving the date/time prompt something like `21:00+4` will result in a timestamp such as:

```
<2015-08-27 Thu 21:00-25:00>
```

What is the correct way to denote such an event?

Comment: Did you try just writing out two timestamps and joining them with a dash?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Org-mode uses two date/timestamps with a `--` to indicate a range. For example:

```
<2015-08-27 Thu>--<2015-08-28 Fri>
```

If you call `org-time-stamp` (`C-c .`, or `C-c !` for inactive timestamps) twice in a row it will automatically insert the dashes to indicate a range.